# how can i convert csv file into an php array?

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file which has three columns; `name`  `age`   `description`

I want to create a function that when called it will convert the csv file and return a php array.

the file is called profiles.csv

```
function convert_csv_to_php{


}
```

How can i implement this in php, i tried looking in the php docs, but it looks really confusing thanks for your help.

Comment: How hard did you look? Because the very first google result if you type in "php csv array" is exactly what you need -- `fgetcsv`.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe this function will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Have you heard of of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)? It was the first result on google...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

#### Sample code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
if (($handle = fopen("smaple.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "$num fields in line $row:\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```